# Is there a way to wrap external type definitions into module?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's assume that we have type provided by some file like **types.d.ts**

```
declare function test(arg: string): void;
```

Is there a way to import types into own type definition and wrapped it into namespace?
i would like to have something like

```
import { test } from 'some-weird-module/types.d.ts';

declare namespace MyModule {
    export test;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My requirements was completely resolved by new TypeScript 3.8 version, they introduced type only imports https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-type-only-imports-and-export

Comment: Please comment your findings. It will be helpful for lot of people.

Answer (score 0):

Types in a `.d.ts` file should not need to be imported => skip `import { test } from 'some-weird-module/types.d.ts';`.

Then, I don't thing that it's possible to wrap these types in a namespace in one line. But, for each type to export, we can try to create a type alias that can be exported:

```js
declare namespace MyModule {
    export type T1bis = T1; // T1 came from 'some-weird-module/types.d.ts'
    export type T2bis = T2; // T2 came from 'some-weird-module/types.d.ts'
    // etc.
}
```